# Would it be wise to put iBeacon monitoring logic in the app delegate in order to live for the duration of the app session?

Tags: ios, ibeacon, appdelegate

I'd like to have my app monitor for iBeacons without being dependent on a certain view controller showing.  In order to avoid duplicating code, should I put the iBeacon monitoring logic in the app delegate?  Basically I'd like for the app to show a local push notification whenever the user enters a region while still being able to look through the app on different screens.

Comment: Yes and no - personally, I'd try and keep the app delegate as clean as possible (it's way to easier for it to end up doing "everything").  Instead, I'd delegate the actual functionality to another class and have the app delegate coordinate it's management as far as it needs to (it should be possible to monitor for app lifecycle events outside of the app delegate ~ so it's question of desired solutions)

Comment: If I went the delegate route, this object would need to be a singleton?  What keywords or resources should I Google for to get an idea of implementing it this way?

Comment: I put a link to an example project that uses a singleton beacon tracking class in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually have to put the logic into the AppDelegate (although for simple apps I often do).  The key thing you need to do so your app gets launched in the background is to **trigger the logic to start monitoring from the AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching method.**  So long as the method call sets up monitoring (even if it does so by calling 
logic in a method in another class). it will lead to your monitoring callback methods being called immediately after.

So long as you hold a reference to the class holding your logic in the AppDelegate (e.g. make its instance a class variable in the AppDelegate) it will not get garbage collected.

If you wish to access state of this class in other parts of your app, you can simply make it a singleton. Then you can call the same class instance to access your beacon tracking state from various view controllers.

You can see an example of this in the [BeaconTracker](https://github.com/davidgyoung/ningo-ios/blob/master/NingoSdkReferenceApp/NingoSdkReferenceApp/BeaconTracker.swift) class I built for an open source project that uses exactly this kind of Singleton approach.  You can browse the AppDelegate and View controllers in the same project to see how it is used.